# How can I control a minimum and maximum numeric value to be displayed based on scroll starting from a specific point on the page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a number that begins to increase when the user gets to an element on the page and then will increase the further down the page they scroll to a maximum number, but the the number will also decrease back to the original number if they scroll up the page.

So far I am only able to make the function start from 0 and increase or decrease on scroll using 'window.scrollY'. Is there a way to set a minimum and maximum?  Or is there a more elegant solution?

Using the example from this thread: [Increase/Decrease variable on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344133/increase-decrease-variable-on-scroll/51344287#51344287)

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    let scrollValue = window.scrollY;
    let num = $("#num");
    num.html(scrollValue);
  });

});
```

`<span id="num"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if this is what you are looking for, but you could maybe map that variable to a different scale? I found this function:

```
const scale = (inputY, yRange, xRange) => {
  const [xMin, xMax] = xRange;
  const [yMin, yMax] = yRange;

  const percent = (inputY - yMin) / (yMax - yMin);
  const outputX = percent * (xMax - xMin) + xMin;

  return outputX;
};
```

So if your scroll variable ranges from 0 - window.innerHeight and you want it to range between 0 and 10, you could use `scale(window.scrollY, [0, window.innerheight], [0, 10])`. This should work.

Comment: That might work, thank you.  This is the closest thing I could find but it's working in reverse of what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579683/jquery-height-altimeter

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some hints:

- [`Element.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) returns the scroll height of any element. To get the height of the whole page, use this method on the root `<html>` or `<body>` element.
- [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) returns the height of the viewport (window).

When the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, the `scrollY` value would be `html.scrollHeight - innerHeight` because `scrollY` is the top of the viewport and `scrollHeight` is the bottom of the viewport.

I'll leave the rest up to you.
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry still learning.  Was able to get that to work in starting from 0 and going to 23,204 by end of scroll.  But I am still trying to figure out how to trigger the start based on an element.  I need to figure out how to trigger with `Element.scrollHeight` I reckon. 


$(document).on('scroll',function() {
   var maxcount = 23204,
    scrollpos = $(document).scrollTop(),
    maxpos = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
    counter = Math.round((scrollpos/maxpos)*(maxcount)) || 0;
    $('#counter').text(counter);
  });

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you trying to do. However, I think you may want to try out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer